# Touchscreen & fingerprint not working Yoga 710-15

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen, input

Touchscreen & fingerprint not working Yoga 710-15(fhd touchscreen, 8RAM, 2gb 940mx, ssd, i7 7500u). Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Kernel version - 4.4.0-57-generic. On ubuntu 14.04.5 the same thing(((

Comment: That would be interesting to see if Ubuntu supports fingerprint readers.. Touch is supported.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04.5 installer with kernel 4.4 - generic support touching, but can't install, cause return fatal error. Elementary installer support it too, but after installation no touch devices detected.